# What do I do wrong when I use database preview via dexplore?

Tags: matlab, ms-access-2007

I have some strange errors when I try to access my MS Access DB via MATLAB. Some hints:

1. The data preview to the tutorial.mdb (shipped with MATLAB) works very well via dexplore - I can see all the tables and I can import the data.
2. The data preview to my own DB works on another system where e.g the language settings differ. -> screenshot 1 This is how the DB preview looks on the other system. Note that table and column names are framed with the ` character. At first the preview resulted in an error too for one of the tables (0433_Slices) - when I renamed it by framing the name with the ' character inside MS Access, I could enforce the table name to be recognized as a string in MATLAB and now this table is importable too.
3. In my system, the preview does not work and gives error messages like "Syntax error in query message" or "Syntax error in FROM clause" "Incomplete query clause" -> screenshot 2 You see here one of the possible error messages, and that neither table nor column names are framed with the ` character. I tried to enforce the recognition of table names by using " characters or ' characters, but that did not work!

Comparing my system to the other system, the most prominent difference is that table names and column names are not recognized as strings (= they are framed with ' characters), and I think this results in the mentioned error messages. Can I fix this somehow, or am I on totally on the wrong track?

Screenshot 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVRDC.png
Screenshot 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvJBF.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited Jan 26 at 16:05

asked Jan 26 at 15:59
R.S.
11

To anybody who will look for a solution for this freak problem in the distant future and finds this thread: neither table names nor column names are allowed to contain a "-" or spaces. "_" is fine though.

Just rename everything using only roman alphabet characters, numbers and "_" and it will work!

Also, dont start with numbers like "032_xyz". It will work if you rename it to "xyz".